# .NET Framework 4.5 is not available in the Target Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I'm on Windows 8.1, and installed VS2013. But I can't find .NET Framework 4.5 in the list of target framework in VS2013.

I have also tried this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx# , and download the SDK 4.5 for VS2013. The installer for .NET Framework 4.5 said "newer framework has been installed".

How do I get .NET 4.5 in the target framework ?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you prefer 4.5 over the newer versions? According to this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn250998.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

it should be available to you. But it seems 4.5.2 is preferred for VS 2013:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That is certainly not the normal target list of VS2013, it knows beans about 4.5.2 and 4.6.1 since its installer doesn't deploy the targeting pack.  It can't, they were released later.  Don't randomly install stuff, spin the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: the common source code in git, is targeting 4.5, and I don't want to change it just because I can't find framework 4.5

Comment: @HansPassant: I have tried repair VS2013, .NET 4.5.1 many times. None of these methods works